# Keras load image from CSV

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, keras

I am want to create a card localizer but don't know how to load the data in my program.

My csv looks like this:

```
imagepath, topleft, topright, bottomleft, bottomright
train_1.jpg, 0.4343242, 0.234234, 0.323523, 0.3242342
```

The image is my input and topleft, topright, bottomleft, bottomright are the labels i want to predict. I have seen a lot of tutorials but they are all on image classification and they use the flow_from_directory but that only works for binary data.

My code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dropout
from keras import losses, optimizers, metrics, layers, models, activations
from keras import backend as K

def get_input_shape(image_width, image_heigth, num_channels):
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        return (num_channels, image_width, image_heigth)
    else:
        return (image_width, image_heigth, num_channels)

def create_model(image_width, image_heigth, num_channels):
    input_shape = get_input_shape(image_width, image_heigth, num_channels)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation=activations.relu, input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation=activations.relu))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation=activations.relu))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation=activations.relu))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512, activation=activations.relu))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation=activations.linear))
    model.compile(loss=losses.mean_squared_error, optimizer=optimizers.sgd(), metrics=[metrics.mean_squared_error])
    model.summary()
    return model

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=40,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

model = create_model(640, 480, 3)
```

I would be nice if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

You have to load the images yourself. Thankfully, you can access Keras functions to do that:

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
img = image.load_img(path, grayscale=False, target_size=None, interpolation='nearest')
img_array = image.img_to_array(img, data_format='channels_last')
```

will give you NumPy arrays back. Now you can load all the images into a single array by processing the CSV file and you get `X=(num_images, W, H, C)` and `Y=(num_images, 4)` so 4 predictions per image. You can still use the extra preprocessing of the ImageDataGenerator by:

```
train_datagen.fit(X) # to compute data dependant statistics
model.fit_generator(train_datagen.flow(X, Y,...), ...)
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed, great explanation!

Comment: @GerjanVlot can you please help me out with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50745516/keras-load-image-from-csv